# Set condition for Controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm having a html form like this:

```
<div class="form-group">                                                                                           
    <labelfor="exampleSelectd">Default Select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="Selection">
        <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
        <option value="Parent">Parent</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and a Script to get value from form above:

```
$.post("Home/Print", {          
    Selection: $("#Selection").val(),
....
})
```

How can I set condition on Controller?
I mean when the user chooses `<option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>`, my Controler will `return WriteFile( ...A.docx....);` and when chooses `<option value="Parent">Parent</option>`, the controller will `return WriteFile( ...B.docx....);`

My Controler like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Print(FormModel document)
{
    if ( condition ) {
        return WriteFile(...A.docx....);
    }
else {
        return WriteFile( ...B.docx....);
    }                    
}    

public class FormModel 
{    
    public string Selection { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `FormModel` class gets filled and injected into the `public string Print` method. Properties of the model/dto can be retrieved using the getters:

```
class FormController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Print(FormModel document)
    {
        if (document.Selection.Equals("Teacher"))
        {
            return WriteFile(...A.docx....);
        }
        else
        {
            return WriteFile(...B.docx....);
        }
    }


}    
public class FormModel {
    public string Selection { get; set; }
}
```